# Zamzar API download failed

Tags: python, api, request

Unable to download the converted file from zamzar api using python program, as specified on the https://developers.zamzar.com/docs but as i am using the code correctly along with api key. It is only showing error code : 20. Wasted 4hour behind this error, someone please.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

file_id =291320
local_filename = 'afzal.txt'
api_key = 'my_key_of_zamzar_api'
endpoint = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/files/{}/content".format(file_id)

response = requests.get(endpoint, stream=True, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key, ''))

try:
  with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
      if chunk:
        f.write(chunk)
        f.flush()

    print("File downloaded")

except IOError:
  print("Error")
```

THis is the code I am using for downloading the converted file.

Comment: Please copy full output/traceback.

Answer (score 2):

This code easily convert files into different formats :

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------#
api_key = 'Put_Your_API_KEY' #your Api_key from developer.zamzar.com
source_file = "tmp/armash.pdf" #source_file_path
target_file = "results/armash.txt" #target_file_path_and_name
target_format = "txt"  #targeted Format.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------#



def check(job_id,api_key):
    check_endpoint = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs/{}".format(job_id)
    response = requests.get(check_endpoint, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key, ''))
    #print(response.json())
    #print(response.json())
    checked_data=response.json()
    value_list=checked_data['target_files']
    #print(value_list[0]['id'])
    return value_list[0]['id']

def download(file_id,api_key,local_filename):
    downlaod_endpoint = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/files/{}/content".format(file_id)
    download_response = requests.get(downlaod_endpoint, stream=True, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key, ''))
    try:
      with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in download_response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
          if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()

        print("File downloaded")

    except IOError:
      print("Error")


endpoint = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs"
file_content = {'source_file': open(source_file, 'rb')}
data_content = {'target_format': target_format}
res = requests.post(endpoint, data=data_content, files=file_content, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key, ''))
print(res.json())
data=res.json()
#print(data)
print("=========== Job ID ============\n\n")
print(data['id'])
target_id=check(data['id'],api_key)
print("\n================= target_id ===========\n\n")
print(target_id)
download(target_id,api_key,target_file)
```

Hope this well somebody!.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the lead developer for the Zamzar API.

So the Zamzar API docs contain a section on error codes (see https://developers.zamzar.com/docs#section-Error_codes). The relevant code for your error is:

> {
>       "message" : "API key was missing or invalid",
>       "code" : 20
>   }

This can mean *either* that you did not specify an API key at all *or* that the API key used was invalid for the file you are attempting to download. It seems more likely to be the latter, since your code contains an `api_key` variable.

Looking at your code it's possible that you have used the **job ID** (291320) to try and download your file, when in fact you should be using a **file ID**.

Each conversion job can output 1 or more converted files and you need to specify the file ID for the one you wish to grab. You can see a list of all converted file ID's for your job by querying `/jobs/ID` and looking at the `target_files` array. This is outlined in the API docs at https://developers.zamzar.com/docs#section-Download_the_converted_file

So if you change your code to use the **file ID** from the `target_files` array of your Job your download should spring into life.

I'm sorry you wasted time on this. Clearly if it has reached S.O. our docs haven't done a good enough job of explaining this distinction so we'll look at what we can do to make them clearer.

Happy converting !

Comment: Yeah, I got the problem later. After wasting 2hrs on it. below I have posted the solution too. which i found later on.  Answer below is the complete solution script from converting the file to downloading it. Take a look!